# Data Control call from Javascript page

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

How to call Existing Oracle ADF Data Control(DataBase Call) from Javascript in JDeveloper?

Answer (score 1):

You can expose your ADF Business Components as REST webservice
(https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/rest_based_crud_with_oracle)
  and consume them from javascript.